# Javascript Pushing Object Into Specific Index

Tags: javascript, php, json, object

I am trying to create a JSON file of data however when I push the object, it's creating another element outside of where it should be.

This is the how the JSON looks after running the code:

```
{
 "level": [
   {
     "6": {
       "TitleEng": "Some English Title",
     }
   },
   {
     "7": {
       "TitleEng": "Some English Title",
     }
   }
 ]
```

}

This is how the JSON should look:

```
{
 "level": [
   {
     "6": {
       "TitleEng": "Some English Title",
     },
     "7": {
       "TitleEng": "Some English Title",
     }
   }
 ]
```

}

I create the object using the following code:

```
$.getJSON( "json/levels.json", function( levels ) {
    obj[lvl] = {
    "TitleEng": titleEng,
    };
    levels.level.push(obj);
    $.post("php/upload_level.php", {json : JSON.stringify(levels)});
});
```

PHP code is as follows:

```
<?php
$json = $_POST['json'];
    if (json_decode($json) != null) {
     $file = fopen('../json/levels.json','w');
     fwrite($file, $json);
     fclose($file);
   } else {
    echo "error writing file";
   }
?>
```

In an attempt to resolve the issue, I tried changing 
    levels.level.push(obj);
to 
    levels.level[0].push(obj);
in order to keep the levels within the level object but this did not work. any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var obj = {
 "level": [
   {
     "6": {
       "TitleEng": "Some English Title",
     },
     "7": {
       "TitleEng": "Some English Title",
     }
   }
 ]};
```

to add a new one to obj

```
obj.level[0][8]= {
           "TitleEng": "Some other English Title",
         }
```

so obj will be

```
{
     "level": [
       {
         "6": {
           "TitleEng": "Some English Title",
         },
         "7": {
           "TitleEng": "Some English Title",
         },
         "8" :{
            "TitleEng": "Some other English Title",
         }
       }
     ]}
```

Comment: This produces the error: cannot set property '8' of undefined

Comment: @NicholasMordecai did you try just my code or tried it along with yours ? I think in your case it should be
     levels.level[0][8]= {
           "TitleEng": "Some other English Title",
         }
instead of
 obj.level[0][8]= {
           "TitleEng": "Some other English Title",
         }